# Goutte driver doesn't i tage supports

Tags: php, html, codeception

I'm using PHPBrowser module for a test where I have the following line

```
$I->click('i.fa.fa-user');
```

but I'm getting an error

```
"Sorry, I couldn't click "i.fa.fa-user":
Behat\Mink\Exception\ElementException: Exception thrown by (//html/descendant-or-self::i[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' fa ') and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' fa-user '))])[1]
Goutte driver supports clicking on inputs and links only. But "i" provided"
```

This is the line of the code

```
<i class="fa fa-user" title="Login"></i>
```

The xpath `i.fa.fa-user` i provided is working when I run browser.
Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: According to the extremely explicit error message, your tool cannot simulate a click to an `i` element. Basically you can change/wrap your tag in an anchor or button, or find another test tool that allows to click on other elements.

Comment: @kuroi neko Thanks for your extremely nice reply.